# How do I configure two routers to advertise the same network out different ports using EIGRP?

Tags: cisco, routing, switch, eigrp

[image]

I have VLAN 3 with the IP address of 172.16.0.1 on R0 and on R2, and I can't get them to ping one another. How do I need to advertise them if they are both on the same network? Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: If you mean each network attached to R0 or R2 is a part of 172.16.0.0/24, then the routers would need to be configured as /25's and the hosts numbered in the correct half of the /24 subnet.  Then you could use proxy-arp to solve this poor design.  Otherwise you need to provide more information about actual subnet details at each location. Or you could interconnect Switch0 and Switch2 and have a relatively standard configuration.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

Long story short, while it is possible to do what you are requesting, it is inadvisable.

With the broad range of the 172.16.0.0 to 172.31.255.255 (1,048,576 total IP addresses) there is really no reason to not further subnet your network and avoid any potential routing issues.

A better setup might be to split the network into 172.16.0.0/25 and 172.16.0.128/25.

Trying to make the current setup work is simply adding more complexity to the system, rather than fixing the underlying issue which is a flawed initial design.

The following document might be sixteen years old, but pretty much everything in it still rings true.  [The Twelve Networking Truths](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1925)

Comment: "With sufficient thrust, pigs fly just fine" … RFC 1925 – Thanks for letting us know about this.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by another responder, this is poor design. I suggest NATing on Router1 and using static routes on Routers 0 and 2 as the best way to get around this.

Answer (score 0):

You would definitely want to break it down further for routing purposes -- you can create a GRE tunnel between R0 and R2, however, to access private ip addresses (and advertise routes) through a public network -- wouldn't really matter if R1 was, in that case, the internet, for example, and R0 was in Australia and R2 was in Canada, for example.

The problem with your proposed setup would be R0, for example, receiving a packet for the same subnet that is behind it...then expecting it to route it out the outside interface instead of the inside interface.  That's where an IPSec s2s VPN could come into play, where you could encapsulate any traffic that matches the destinations on the other side, then appropriately route them through the tunnel.

Hope that helps.